# checking the length WP_Query(array())

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello Everyone i am trying to displaying some information if the below query has no results . Something like `<P> There are no upcoming Events</p>`

How can i check the lenght for the array to know if it contains posts

Here is the code

```
<?php
                $now = date('Ymd');
                $frontPageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
                  'posts_per_page' => 2,
                  'post_type' => 'event',
                  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'key' => 'event_date',
                      'compare' => '>=',
                      'value' => $now,
                      'type' => 'numeric'
                    )
                  )


                ));


                  while ($frontPageEvents -> have_posts()){
                    $frontPageEvents -> the_post();

                    ?>


                    <div class="">
                      <div class="">
                        <div class=""> <?php
                        $date = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
                         echo $date->format('d');
                        ?> <br> <?php echo $date->format('M'); ?></div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="">
                        <img class=""src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('eventFrontThumbnail') ?>" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="">
                        <div class="">
                          <h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class=""><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(),10); ?></div>


                        <div class=""> <p>

                          <a class="btn btn-primary"href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more...</a>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  <?php } ?>
```

So before the

```
while ($frontPageEvents -> have_posts()){
                    $frontPageEvents -> the_post();

                    ?>
```

if there are no upcoimg events, i want to display a paragraph instead with some notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some condition:

```
<?php if (!$frontPageEvents->have_posts()){ ?>
    <p> some thing </p>
<?php }

while ($frontPageEvents -> have_posts()){
    $frontPageEvents -> the_post();
?>
...
```

The function `have_posts()` returns a boolean. You can read the docs here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the array is empty using the empty function.

```
if (empty($frontPageEvents)) {
    echo 'There are no upcoming events';
} else {
        while ($frontPageEvents -> have_posts()){
               $frontPageEvents -> the_post();
  ?>
```

Don't forget the closing brace `}` after the events are output if there were any.